# What is the proper implementation for test cases which accept similar type of input parameter,same implementation code but different output

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, junit4

**Which one is advisable to use out of the two ?**

When there is "same implementation" testcode but "different output" because "slight difference in input" i.e `input1` and `input2` has minor difference. "Suppose input1 is empty list and input2 is parameterized list"

let have a dummy code for two possibilities of test Classes :

**Both Behaviour is achieved from same Test method i.e :**

```
public Class DataProvider{

  private static setUp(){
  }

  public static Object[][] data_all_Behaviour(){
   setUp();
   return new Object[][]{
                         {"DataForBehavior1",Input1,Output1},
                         {"DataForBehavior2",Input2,Output2}};
                        }
  }
}


@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class TestClass{
  @Parameters(class=DataProvider.class)
  public void Test_all_Behaviour(String message,Input inp, Output out){
     //execute input and verify output and display message
  }
}
```

**Here for each behaviour ,there is separate test method.**

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)

    public class TestClass{

      public Object[][] data_for_Behaviour1(){
       setUp();
       return new Object[][]{
                             {"DataForBehavior1",Input1,Output1}
                            }
      }


      public void test_Behaviour1(String message,Input inp, Output out){
         //execute input and verify output and display message
      }
    }


      public Object[][] data_for_Behaviour2(){
       setUp();
       return new Object[][]{
                             {"DataForBehavior2",Input2,Output2}
                            }
      }


      public void test_Behaviour2(String message,Input inp, Output out){
         //execute input and verify output and display message
      }
    }
}
```

Also provide other possible ways to achieve the same ?

Comment: If you used TestNG you could have used a `@DataProvider` for that. JUnit still sucks at parameterized tests.

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable, as long as you are using a common test helper method instead of copy/paste for the second option with two tests.  Use whichever is most understandable for you and your team.